# Linkedin api.linkedin.com/v1/people started returning 400 error

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have an web application which has been working fine for years using `api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares`. No code has been changed.

From now on, all calls to this api is returning 400.

See one example:

`url:`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth_token=xxxxx

`Request Method: POST`

`Body:`

```
{  
   "content":{  
      "title":"text title",
      "submitted-url":"http://my-domain-url/resource",
      "submitted-image-url":"http://my-domain-url/image.jpg"
   },
   "comment":"text title",
   "visibility":{  
      "code":"anyone"
   }
}
```

Response:

```
Status Code: 400 
Body
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Can not parse JSON share document.\nRequest body:\n\nError:\nnull",
  "requestId": "Y9RHPVP9GP",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1548417237616
}
```

This is the javascript snippet to make the call

```
IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
          .method("POST")
          .body(body)
          .result(function (data) {
            $scope.linkedIn.shared = true;
            $scope.linkedIn.url = data.updateUrl;
            $('#successDialog').modal('toggle');
            $scope.addSharesCount(jobDetails.jobId);
          })

          .error(function (error) {
              $scope.error.body = 'error.message;
               $scope.$apply();
               $('#errorDialog').modal('show');
    }
```

I have found this: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

Says we all should migrate to new api by March first. Which looks too short to me.

Also it seems there's a non compatible change or bug in the /v1 api.

Comment: Added javascript code making the call to the api

Answer (score 1):

V1 is retired now so you need to move to v2
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Answer (score 0):

400 http error code means "Bad Request" (if you don't know what your http code means, you can use [http.cat](https://http.cat)), so probably missing User-Agent, try to put one from a real browser, some api refuses when the client has no User-Agent/Bot User-Agent.

You have to put this in request header.

Example User-Agent :

```
   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
```

Have a good day programming o/

Comment: Hey thanks for the link but I know what's bad request and most of the http codes and the http protocol itself. 
User-Agent is already added to the header. I can list all request headers here, but not sure if it's gonna help much.

Json is well formatted and has been working fine for ages. That response seems to me they changed the protocol (bug on their side). as there's no recent changes in this web app.

Comment: I think they killed api v1

Comment: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates says it should last until March 1st. :( 
Hope someone (developer) from linkedin could check this...